# Nav Bar Button Item "Compose" shifts to the right during segue

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

When segueing from one view with a standard Nav Bar Button Item of type "Compose" to another view with the same Nav Bar Button, the icon shifts a few pixels to the right.

Here is what it looks like:

[image]

If I change the Nav Bar Button Item to a different type, such as "Add", this odd behavior is not observed. I've also tried changing the Bar Item Image Offsets and the Bar Button Item Width. Neither of those solved the issue.

There's really nothing complex about my setup. I just dragged the Bar Button Item from the object library into the Nav bar and changed `Identifier` to "Compose" for both view controllers. That's it.

Does anyone know how to get around this?

**EDIT**

This appears to be a bug in iOS. I've seen this same issue in various apps.

Comment: I think it might be adjusting for your text.

Comment: I removed the nav bar text on all the view controllers, and it still moves about on segue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We're having the same issue. It seems like a bug in iOS.

**Workaround:** Use a custom bar button item with your own "compose" image.

In order to use the very same image as the system compose icon, you can use iOS Artwork Extractor: https://github.com/0xced/iOS-Artwork-Extractor

Comment: note: this should also be ok for app submission as long as you use the extracted icon for it's intended purpose. i.e don't use the extracted "Edit" button for "Settings" etc

Comment: @Mark That has nothing to do with the Artwork Extractor, as you can already use the system Edit button to open the settings.